# Accessing Access database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script below to insert into an access database :

```
// Create an instance of the ADO connection object
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

// Define the connection string and specify the database driver
$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=".realpath("mypath/database.accdb").";Persist Security Info=False;";

// Open the connection to the database
$conn->open($connStr);


$query = "INSERT INTO [Valuations] (my insert code)";


try{
$rs = $conn->execute($query);
} catch(com_exception $e){
        echo($e);
    }
```

I have this on my IIS website, and it inserts into the database fine if i make a copy of the database and put it in the same folder as the script.

The problem is the database is on the k:/ drive of the server and the script is on c:/inetpubs, so i am getting an authorization error. I have all the required permissions set i can even put in the link from the .realpath in the url and the database starts downloading.

I created a virtual folder in iis to link to the database on the k:/ drive, but i keep getting the ADODB.Connection authorization error.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: may be your database has user and password ?

Comment: if you move the database to the C: drive (just for testing purposes) does the error go away?

Comment: Yeah it works when i do that @ADyson

Comment: @Wizard no the database doesn't have a username and password, the insert works if the database is in the c drive within the website

Comment: "i can even put in the link from the .realpath in the url and the database starts downloading". Don't make the database accessible over the web! There's absolutely no need to do this, it's a massive security risk.

Comment: have you tried making it a network share instead of a mapped drive in the connection string (e.g. in the form \\server\share\database.accdb)?

Comment: P.s. what _exactly_ does the error message say?